# Get name of players and numbers which players has "shot"

Tags: c#, list, input, get, project

I am working on a Windows form, I have two lists: one for the names of players, and one for the numbers which the players have guessed. With this code I get in listbox name of all players, but the problem is I can get only number from last player which are same with numbers which are generated from system and the numbers which player has guessed, but I need to know how to get numbers which are same from two lists for every players, example:

Player 1:
2, 3 , 28 // has three numbers same from the lists
Player 2:
1
etc..

I wrote this code:

```
namespace LojaFatitForm
{
public partial class Loja_e_Fatit : Form
{
    public Loja_e_Fatit()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    int player = 1;
    int Guessed=0;

    int ticket = 1;
    string t = "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
    List<string> nameOfPlayers = new List<string>();
    List<string> choosedNumbers = new List<string>();
    List<string> winningNumbers = new List<string>();
    List<string> guessedNumbers = new List<string>();
    private void Loja_e_Fatit_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { } 

    private void bntGenerateNr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int Mosha;
        Int32.TryParse(txtMosha.Text, out Mosha);
        if (Mosha < 18)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Lojtari duhet te jete ne moshen madhore!");
            txtMosha.Text = "";
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtMosha.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtEmri.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtMbiemri.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtQyteti.Text)
            || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtNr1.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtNr2.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtNr3.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtNr4.Text) 
            || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtNr5.Text)|| string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtNr6.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtNr7.Text))              
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ju lutemi jepni te dhenat/Numrat tuaja!");
        }
        else 

            if(txtNr2==txtNr1 || txtNr2==txtNr3 )
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ky numur edhe dhene, jepni nje numer tjeter!");
                txtNr2.Text = "";
            }
        else
             if (txtNr3 == txtNr2 || txtNr3==txtNr1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ky numur edhe dhene, jepni nje numer tjeter!");
            txtNr3.Text = "";
        }else
             if (txtNr4 == txtNr1 || txtNr4==txtNr3 || txtNr4==txtNr2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ky numur edhe dhene, jepni nje numer tjeter!");
            txtNr4.Text = "";
        }else
             if (txtNr5 == txtNr1 || txtNr5==txtNr2 || txtNr5==txtNr3 || txtNr5==txtNr4)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ky numur edhe dhene, jepni nje numer tjeter!");
            txtNr5.Text = "";
        }
        else
             if (txtNr6 == txtNr1 || txtNr6==txtNr2 || txtNr6==txtNr3 || txtNr6==txtNr4 || txtNr6==txtNr5)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ky numur edhe dhene, jepni nje numer tjeter!");
            txtNr6.Text = "";
        }else
             if (txtNr7 == txtNr1 || txtNr7==txtNr2 || txtNr7==txtNr3 || txtNr7==txtNr4 || txtNr7==txtNr5 || txtNr7==txtNr6)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ky numur edhe dhene, jepni nje numer tjeter!");
            txtNr7.Text = "";
        }

        else
        {

            Random r = new Random();
            int Nr1, Nr2, Nr3, Nr4, Nr5, Nr6, Nr7;

            Int32.TryParse(txtNr1Gen.Text, out Nr1);
            Nr1 = r.Next(1, 39);
            txtNr1Gen.Text = Nr1.ToString();
            if ((txtNr1Gen.Text == txtNr1.Text) || (txtNr1Gen.Text == txtNr2.Text) || (txtNr1Gen.Text == txtNr3.Text) ||
             (txtNr1Gen.Text == txtNr4.Text) || (txtNr1Gen.Text == txtNr5.Text) || (txtNr1Gen.Text == txtNr6.Text) || (txtNr1Gen.Text == txtNr7.Text))
            {
                winningNumbers.Add(txtNr1Gen.Text);
                Guessed++;
            }


            Int32.TryParse(txtNr2Gen.Text, out Nr2);
            nr2: Nr2 = r.Next(1, 39);
            if (Nr2 == Nr1)
            {
                goto nr2;
            }
            else
            {
                txtNr2Gen.Text = Nr2.ToString();
                if ((txtNr2Gen.Text == txtNr1.Text) || (txtNr2Gen.Text == txtNr2.Text) || (txtNr2Gen.Text == txtNr3.Text) ||
            (txtNr2Gen.Text == txtNr4.Text) || (txtNr2Gen.Text == txtNr5.Text) || (txtNr2Gen.Text == txtNr6.Text) || (txtNr2Gen.Text == txtNr7.Text))
                {
                    winningNumbers.Add(txtNr2Gen.Text);
                    Guessed++;
                }
            }

            Int32.TryParse(txtNr3Gen.Text, out Nr3);
            nr3: Nr3 = r.Next(1, 39);
            if (Nr3 == Nr2 || Nr3 == Nr1)
            {
                goto nr3;
            }
            else
            {
                txtNr3Gen.Text = Nr3.ToString();
                if ((txtNr3Gen.Text == txtNr1.Text) || (txtNr3Gen.Text == txtNr2.Text) || (txtNr3Gen.Text == txtNr3.Text) ||
            (txtNr3Gen.Text == txtNr4.Text) || (txtNr3Gen.Text == txtNr5.Text) || (txtNr3Gen.Text == txtNr6.Text) || (txtNr3Gen.Text == txtNr7.Text))
                {
                    winningNumbers.Add(txtNr3Gen.Text);
                    Guessed++;
                }
            }

            Int32.TryParse(txtNr4Gen.Text, out Nr4);
            nr4: Nr4 = r.Next(1, 39);
            if (Nr4 == Nr3 || Nr4 == Nr2 || Nr4 == Nr1)
            {
                goto nr4;
            }
            else
            {
                txtNr4Gen.Text = Nr4.ToString();
                if ((txtNr4Gen.Text == txtNr1.Text) || (txtNr4Gen.Text == txtNr2.Text) || (txtNr4Gen.Text == txtNr3.Text) ||
           (txtNr4Gen.Text == txtNr4.Text) || (txtNr4Gen.Text == txtNr5.Text) || (txtNr4Gen.Text == txtNr6.Text) || (txtNr4Gen.Text == txtNr7.Text))
                {
                    winningNumbers.Add(txtNr4Gen.Text);
                    Guessed++;
                }
            }

            Int32.TryParse(txtNr5Gen.Text, out Nr5);
            nr5: Nr5 = r.Next(1, 39);
            if (Nr5 == Nr4 || Nr5 == Nr3 || Nr5 == Nr2 || Nr5 == Nr1)
            {
                goto nr5;
            }
            else
            {
                txtNr5Gen.Text = Nr5.ToString();
                if ((txtNr5Gen.Text == txtNr1.Text) || (txtNr5Gen.Text == txtNr2.Text) || (txtNr5Gen.Text == txtNr3.Text) ||
            (txtNr5Gen.Text == txtNr4.Text) || (txtNr5Gen.Text == txtNr5.Text) || (txtNr5Gen.Text == txtNr6.Text) || (txtNr5Gen.Text == txtNr7.Text))
                {
                    winningNumbers.Add(txtNr5Gen.Text);
                    Guessed++;
                }
            }

            Int32.TryParse(txtNr6Gen.Text, out Nr6);
            nr6: Nr6 = r.Next(1, 39);
            if (Nr6 == Nr5 || Nr6 == Nr4 || Nr6 == Nr3 || Nr6 == Nr2 || Nr6 == Nr1)
            {
                goto nr6;
            }
            else
            {
                txtNr6Gen.Text = Nr6.ToString();
                if ((txtNr6Gen.Text == txtNr1.Text) || (txtNr6Gen.Text == txtNr2.Text) || (txtNr6Gen.Text == txtNr3.Text) ||
           (txtNr6Gen.Text == txtNr4.Text) || (txtNr6Gen.Text == txtNr5.Text) || (txtNr6Gen.Text == txtNr6.Text) || (txtNr6Gen.Text == txtNr7.Text))
                {
                    winningNumbers.Add(txtNr6Gen.Text);
                    Guessed++;
                }
            }

            Int32.TryParse(txtNr7Gen.Text, out Nr7);
            nr7: Nr7 = r.Next(1, 39);
            if (Nr7 == Nr6 || Nr7 == Nr5 || Nr7 == Nr4 || Nr7 == Nr3 || Nr7 == Nr2 || Nr7 == Nr1)
            {
                goto nr7;
            }
            else
            {
                txtNr7Gen.Text = Nr7.ToString();
                if ((txtNr7Gen.Text == txtNr1.Text) || (txtNr7Gen.Text == txtNr2.Text) || (txtNr7Gen.Text == txtNr3.Text) ||
           (txtNr7Gen.Text == txtNr4.Text) || (txtNr7Gen.Text == txtNr5.Text) || (txtNr7Gen.Text == txtNr6.Text) || (txtNr7Gen.Text == txtNr7.Text))
                {
                    winningNumbers.Add(txtNr7Gen.Text);
                    Guessed++;
                }
            }


            updateListbox("");
            updateListbox("Random numbers generated are:" + txtNr1Gen.Text + " " + txtNr2Gen.Text + " " + txtNr3Gen.Text + " " + txtNr4Gen.Text + " " + txtNr5Gen.Text + " " + txtNr6Gen.Text + " " + txtNr7Gen.Text);

            updateListbox(t);
        }

        bntGenerateNr.Enabled = false;
        btnNewPlayer.Enabled = false;
        btnSave.Enabled = false;

        foreach (var i in choosedNumbers)
        {
            foreach (var j in winningNumbers)
            {
                if (i == j)
                {
                    guessedNumbers.Add(i);

                }
            }
        }

        foreach (var i in nameOfPlayers)
        {
            if (Guessed < 1)
            {
                updateListbox("There are no winners in this round!");
            }
            else
            {
                updateListbox("Player: " + i + " has guessed " + Guessed + " Numbers: ");
                updateListbox(string.Join(", ", guessedNumbers));
                foreach (var j in guessedNumbers)
                {
                    updateListbox(j);
                }
            }
        }





    }
    private void updateListbox(string value)
    {
        Lista.Items.Add(value);
        Lista.TabIndex = Lista.Items.Count - 1;
    }

    private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainForm main = new MainForm();
        this.Hide();
        main.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnNewPlayer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtNr1.Text = null;
        txtNr2.Text = null;
        txtNr3.Text = null;
        txtNr4.Text = null;
        txtNr5.Text = null;
        txtNr6.Text = null;
        txtNr7.Text = null;
        txtEmri.Text = "";
        txtMbiemri.Text = "";
        txtMosha.Text = "";
        txtQyteti.Text = "";
        txtId.Text = "";
        player++;
        ticket++;

    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        updateListbox("Ticket: " + ticket);
        // Validimet per numrat e dhene

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtNr1.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtNr2.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtNr3.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtNr4.Text)
            || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtNr5.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtNr6.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtNr7.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Give some number at any of 7 numbers");
        }
        else

        if (txtNr1.Text == txtNr2.Text || txtNr1.Text == txtNr3.Text || txtNr1.Text == txtNr4.Text || txtNr1.Text == txtNr5.Text || txtNr1.Text == txtNr6.Text || txtNr1.Text == txtNr7.Text)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Choose different number from the others at 1st!");
            txtNr1.Text = "";
        }
        else
             if (txtNr2.Text == txtNr3.Text || txtNr2.Text == txtNr4.Text || txtNr2.Text == txtNr5.Text || txtNr2.Text == txtNr6.Text || txtNr2.Text == txtNr7.Text)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Choose different number from the others at 2nd!");
            txtNr2.Text = "";
        }
        else
             if (txtNr3.Text == txtNr4.Text || txtNr3.Text == txtNr5.Text || txtNr3.Text == txtNr6.Text || txtNr3.Text == txtNr7.Text)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Choose different number from the others at 3d!");
            txtNr3.Text = "";
        }
        else
             if (txtNr4.Text == txtNr5.Text || txtNr4.Text == txtNr6.Text || txtNr4.Text == txtNr7.Text)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Choose different number from the others at 4th!");
            txtNr4.Text = "";
        }
        else
             if (txtNr5.Text == txtNr6.Text || txtNr5.Text == txtNr7.Text)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Choose different number from the others at 5th!");
            txtNr5.Text = "";
        }
        else
             if (txtNr6.Text == txtNr7.Text)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Choose different number from the others at 6th!");
            txtNr6.Text = "";
        }
        else
        if (Convert.ToInt32(txtNr1.Text) < 1 || Convert.ToInt32(txtNr1.Text) > 39)
        {
            txtNr1.Text = "";
            MessageBox.Show("Please write 1st numbers because is out of range!");
        }
        else
        if (Convert.ToInt32(txtNr2.Text) < 1 || Convert.ToInt32(txtNr2.Text) > 39)
        {
            txtNr2.Text = "";
            MessageBox.Show("Please write 2nd numbers because is out of range!!");
        }
        else
        if (Convert.ToInt32(txtNr3.Text) < 1 || Convert.ToInt32(txtNr3.Text) > 39)
        {
            txtNr3.Text = "";
            MessageBox.Show("Please write 3d numbers because is out of range!!");
        }
        else
        if (Convert.ToInt32(txtNr4.Text) < 1 || Convert.ToInt32(txtNr4.Text) > 39)
        {
            txtNr4.Text = "";
            MessageBox.Show("Please write 4th numbers because is out of range!!");
        }
        else
        if (Convert.ToInt32(txtNr5.Text) < 1 || Convert.ToInt32(txtNr5.Text) > 39)
        {
            txtNr5.Text = "";
            MessageBox.Show("Please write 5th numbers because is out of range!!");
        }
        else
        if (Convert.ToInt32(txtNr6.Text) < 1 || Convert.ToInt32(txtNr6.Text) > 39)
        {
            txtNr6.Text = "";
            MessageBox.Show("Please write 6th numbers because is out of range!!");
        }
        else
        if ((Convert.ToInt32(txtNr7.Text) < 1 || Convert.ToInt32(txtNr7.Text) > 39))
        {
            txtNr7.Text = "";
            MessageBox.Show("Please write 7th numbers because is out of range!!");
        }


        else
        {
            updateListbox("Player " + txtEmri.Text + " choosed :" + txtNr1.Text + " " + txtNr2.Text + " " + txtNr3.Text +
                " " + txtNr4.Text + " " + txtNr5.Text + " " + txtNr6.Text + " " + txtNr7.Text);
            choosedNumbers.Add(txtNr1.Text);
            choosedNumbers.Add(txtNr2.Text);
            choosedNumbers.Add(txtNr3.Text);
            choosedNumbers.Add(txtNr4.Text);
            choosedNumbers.Add(txtNr5.Text);
            choosedNumbers.Add(txtNr6.Text);
            choosedNumbers.Add(txtNr7.Text);
        }
        nameOfPlayers.Add(txtEmri.Text);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: you should [provide code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you came up with.

Comment: try a Linq [Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming, since we don't know what is the code of your `updateListbox()` method, that it replaces everything in the display box.

As such, you would need something like this:

```
foreach (var i in emrateLojtarve)
{
    if (teQelluar < 1)
    {
        updateListbox("Ne kete gjiro nuk ka fituar asnje lojtar!");
    }
    else
    {
        updateListbox("Player: " + i + " ka te qelluara " + teQelluar + " Numra: ");
        updateListbox(string.Join(", ", numrateQelluar));
    }
}
```